# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceed when closing a BrowserWindow that is inside an tupple array

Tags: javascript, typescript, electron

I'm tring to close a window that is stored in a tupple array, but I'm getting `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceed` when I call the `BrowserWindow.close()` method.

**Example:**

```
let windows [view, BrowserWindow][] = []
let window = new BrowserWindow()

window.on('close', (event) => {
     this.closeWindow(event.sender.id)     
})
```

This method gets the window with the same id and calls the `.close()` method, when it uses the `.close()` method it gives me the error.

I know that is from the `.close()` method because I've tried other methods, like `.setSize()` and  worked fine

Comment: `this.closeWindow` fires `close` which invokes `closeWindow` which fires `close` etc...

Comment: Wha do you mean?

Comment: @georg, you mean that it enters in a recursive mode?

Comment: We'll need to see what `closeWindow` is doing.. also the first line in your snippet is invalid. is there a typo?